# Android Application does not support this device

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe, android-virtual-device, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to develop an easy app with Delphi Xe7 with just a "Hello World". The program is compiled right and executed right, but the avd emulator says "Application does not support this device". The app appears in the avd.

I have tried with different android versions from 2.3 to 4.4 and in all of them the same problem appears .

Answer (score 1):

Your AVD does not satisfy the hardware requirements for Delphi Android apps.  Read [Embarcadero's documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development), and also the [Delphi Wikia page](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) (which lists more devices than Embarcadero does).

Answer (score 0):

If your device satisfies all the conditions but message show again. 
You can try:

```
1. In the Delphi IDE, open the Deployment Manager (Project -> Deployment), and locate the following entry:
  Local Name: libnative-activity.so 
  Remote Path: library\lib\armeabi\ 
2. Uncheck the entry to prevent deployment of this file.
```

Source: [Application does not support this device](http://mirsovetov.net/application-not-support-device.html)